# What are the ways to help my cats feel better during a heatwave?

Tags: cats, temperature

Recently, the majority of UK was hit with heatwaves, and as I am writing this, it's a flaming 90 °F (32 °C). Comparisons aside, it is the hottest it has been in the past few years, for London.

Since yesterday, one of my cats exhibited some behaviour where she would lie down and hug the cool wall, while stretched out. Overall, my cats seem to be slightly affected by the heat, as seen from them constantly lying down stretched out as much as it's possible for them, in shady areas. We don't let them go outside due to living next to an active road.

Last night, my mother gave us wet mini towels to cool our bodies down during the night, so that we can sleep comfortably, etc. (Note: she didn't give the towels to cats, to clarify. We have other family members as well). Today, I came up with an idea to put a moist towel on my cat's belly, while she was 'sunbathing' in front of the window. She seemed very grateful, started purring, nudging my hand with her nose, so I assumed I did a good thing for her. She then fell asleep. She is currently still sleeping.

Is this a good thing if it's not too wet?

What other ways are there to help my cats feel more comfortable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/13777/6901) answer of mine for a few suggestions. Also a rubbing a cat down with a wet towel is perfectly fine. In fact if it is very hot it is definitely encouraged as long as your cat isnt stressed from it!

Also it is natural for cats to be lazy during heatwaves. They dont want to make themselves warmer and overheat. Many people are the same way, i think. Try to play with them less when it is so warm because you dont want them to overexert themselves.